# transpose data set followed by sorting. Then, create new data set

Tags: python, list, numpy

Data set we have is here.

```
a=np.array([2,6,9,5])
b =np.array([0.5,3,1,4])
```

what I'm looking for is (sorted data points by a)

```
a=np.array([2,5,6,9])
b =np.array([0.5,4,3,1])
```

The code I've been trying and gives me an error

If you can teach me the error, it would be very appreciable. I search answers for this, but I couldn't find out. Thank you so much in advance.

```
import numpy as np
a=np.array([2,6,9,5])
b =np.array([0.5,3,1,4])

#transpose data points
datatemp = np.array([a, b]).T

data=sorted(datatemp, key=itemgetter(0))

a=data[:,0]
b=data[:,1]
print(a)
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't actually need to do any of this crazy transpose stuff. The function [`np.argsort()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html) is designed for this kind of stuff.

```
a = np.array([2,6,9,5])
b = np.array([0.5,3,1,4])
arg_order = np.argsort(a)

a = a[arg_order]
b = b[arg_order]

print(a)
print(b)
#: array([2, 5, 6, 9])
#: array([ 0.5,  4. ,  3. ,  1. ])
```

If you look at the value of `arg_order`, all it is is an array of which indexes to retrieve in the correct order.

```
print(arg_order)
#: array([0, 3, 1, 2])
```

Numpy arrays can take arrays as index arguments which describe what order to retrieve what elements in. (Give me a new array with the `0th`, then the `3rd`, then the `1st` then the `2nd` elements in that order).

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for. Works great in my code. Thank you.